# How to add capabilities to Azure container instances?

Tags: azure

I see options to add capabilities for aws fargate containers such as SYS_PTRACE. Does Azure container instances support such options? If so, how can I do it in the yaml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible in ACI

Comment: Do you mean SYS_PTRACE is not possible or ACI does not support any capabilities?

Comment: ACI does not support setting any capabilities

Comment: Hijacking the thread a bit, need to be able to set iptables redirection rules inside a container in order to forward TCP via SOCKS5 without making the different initiating clients use SOCKS5, iptables modifications need NET_ADMIN, is there still no support what so ever in ACI for  cap-add:<CAPABILITY>? @SamCogan
Do I in that case need to run AKS or Azure VM as a self managed container runner to support the case?

Comment: @Kristofer I suggest creating a new question for this.

Comment: @Kristofer I was looking for something similar did you ever figure out a solution or did you go for the full vm?