# What capabilities do Azure Container Instances support?

Tags: azure

Last year, a question was posted about how to add capabilities to an ACI. The accepted answer was that it wasn't possible: [How to add capabilities to Azure container instances?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1089384/how-to-add-capabilities-to-azure-container-instances)

However, the documentation for the CLI has a parameter to do so, but I cannot find what capabilities are supported.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-container-create

```
--add-capabilities
A List of security context capabilities to be added
```

.